# chrome extension check failing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I currently have the scripts below. However, it always shows alert 'test2'. Something is wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

**inject.js**

```
(function setExtended() {
     window.extended = 1;
});
```

**website**

```
<script>
    var extended; 

    function extension(){
        if (! extended){
            alert('test2');
        } else {
            alert('test3');
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: maybe the space between ! and extended in your if?

Comment: @Cracker0dks No, because even without it, it always gives me test2 as an alert.

Comment: yes because you define and check extended and not window.extended... remove the "var extended" and add "window.extended" to the if.

Comment: and if you want to call the anonyme function directly, the ending should look like this "})();"

Comment: @Cracker0dks that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the `window` object you use does not refer to the same `window` object that the variable is attached to. In a Chrome extension, there is the background context with its own `window` variable and there is the context of the current window/tab you are on. Make sure you are accessing the right `window` object.

It's also possible that the `extension()` function is called before the `setExtended()` function in which case it will always alert 'test2'. Use the Chrome DevTools and set breakpoints to make sure they are called in the correct order.

Hope I helped. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Well, I certainly understand what you're saying and what you mean. However, I don't know what you mean by 'Use the Chrome DevTools and set breakpoints to make sure they are called in the correct order.'

Comment: ok so what I mean is this: go to your "website" and right click anywhere on the sight and click "Inspect Element". Then go to the "sources" tab and press ctrl-O to open up the related Javascript file. Once you have the Javascript files open, click on a line number to set a breakpoint in both the "extension" function and the "setExtended" function. Then press ctrl-R to refresh and see what is called first. It will also show if any errors occured in the "console" tab.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript context of the page and the content_script are separate and do not share variables/functions/etc. You should use [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) as [described here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).